# ADD/UPDATE BUTTON syntax error

Tags: vba, command, ms-access-2013

Im currently coding my Add/Update button in MS Access 2013 but for some odd reason im having trouble trying to make it work all it tells me is that I have a 'syntax error on the UPDATE statement'... here is my code overall:

```
    Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'In the button add we have two options
    '1. Insert
    '2. Update
    If Me.txtID.Tag & "" = "" Then

    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblClients ( ClientID, ClientName, Gender, " & _
                             "City, [Address (Fisical)], [Cellphone/Telephone] ) " & _
                                "SELECT " & Me.txtID & ",'" & Me.txtName & "','" & Me.cboGender & "', '" & Me.cboCity & "','" & Me.txtAddress & "','" & Me.txtCellphone & "'"
    Else
    'Otherwise the data will be updated
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblClients" & _
    "SET ClientID =" & Me.txtID & _
    ", ClientName='" & Me.txtName & "'" & _
    ", Gender='" & Me.cboGender & "'" & _
    ", City='" & Me.cboCity & "'" & _
    ", Cellphone/Telephone='" & Me.txtCellphone & "'" & _
    ", Address (Fisical) ='" & Me.txtAddress & "'" & _
    "WHERE ClientID =" & Me.txtID.Tag


    End If


   cmdClear_Click

   tblClients_subform.Form.Requery


   End Sub
```

please help needed

Comment: Likely a datatyping error, why are the references to `Me.TxtId` and `Me.TxtId.Tag` not encapsulated with single quotes?  Are these fields not returning strings, like textboxes usually do?

Comment: Bracket field names which include any characters other than letters, digits, and underscore (`_`): `[Cellphone/Telephone]` and `[Address (Fisical)]`  In other words, do those field names for the `UPDATE` as you did them for the `INSERT`.

Comment: Consider switching to parameter queries instead of concatenating values into SQL statement text.

Comment: I did tried encapsulating me.txtID and me.txtId.Tag but it gave me an error when compiling it, something like statement expected, already bracket the fields but it does the same, same syntax error, and Im having trouble changing the values into SQL statement text :S....pretty confused, I know SQL but Im not that experienced with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks close, think of it this way because i know it frustrates me when it happens. If the error says syntax error, its not lying, and more often than not for me it was not being able to see the wood for the trees. You're missing a few spaces:-

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [tblClients]" & _
" SET [ClientID] =" & Me.txtID & _
", [ClientName]='" & Me.txtName & "'" & _
", [Gender]='" & Me.cboGender & "'" & _
", [City]='" & Me.cboCity & "'" & _
", [Cellphone/Telephone]='" & Me.txtCellphone & "'" & _
", [Address (Fisical)] ='" & Me.txtAddress & "'" & _
" WHERE [ClientID] =" & Me.txtID.Tag
```

- Space before `SET ClientID...`
- Space before `WHERE ClientID`
- Bracket column and table names

Also a trick I learned for this: -

1. Open a new query and view the SQL
2. Paste the string that would have been executed into it
3. Run it

You get more info on where the issue is.