# SQL syntax error on vba

Tags: sql, vba

I made a SQL statement in the add/update button in the query wizard I changed it back to SQL view to see how the program made me the code and when I copy and paste the same error on the If statement of the btnAdd it throws me a syntax error, but how?

here is the entire code:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
   'In the button add we have two options
   '1. Insert
   '2. Update
   If Me.txtID.Tag & "" = "" Then

   CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblClients ( ClientID, ClientName, Gender, " & _
                         "City, [Address (Fisical)], [Cellphone/Telephone] ) " & _
                            "SELECT " & Me.txtID & ",'" & Me.txtName & "','" & Me.cboGender & "', '" & Me.cboCity & "','" & Me.txtAddress & "','" & Me.txtCellphone & "'"
   Else
   'Otherwise the data will be updated
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblClients SET tblClients.ClientName = [me].    [txtName], tblClients.Gender = [me].[cboGender], tblClients.City = [me].[cboCity], tblClients.[Address (Fisical)] = [me].[txtAddress], tblClients.[Cellphone/Telephone] = [me].[txtCellphone] "
    WHERE (([ClientID]=[Me].[txtID].[Tag]));

    End If


    cmdClear_Click

    tblClients_subform.Form.Requery


End Sub
```

it highlights me this row in red:

```
WHERE (([ClientID]=[Me].[txtID].[Tag]));
```

Comment: Change the Select keyword to VALUES in your insert statement. You might need parentheses too.

Comment: SQL Injection risk. Use parameterisation!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the following code is not on the same line

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblClients SET tblClients.ClientName = [me].    [txtName], tblClients.Gender = [me].[cboGender], tblClients.City = [me].[cboCity], tblClients.[Address (Fisical)] = [me].[txtAddress], tblClients.[Cellphone/Telephone] = [me].[txtCellphone] "
    WHERE (([ClientID]=[Me].[txtID].[Tag]))
```

So you may want to change it to

```
 CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblClients SET tblClients.ClientName = [me].    [txtName], tblClients.Gender = [me].[cboGender], tblClients.City = [me].[cboCity], tblClients.[Address (Fisical)] = [me].[txtAddress], tblClients.[Cellphone/Telephone] = [me].[txtCellphone] " & _
    "WHERE (([ClientID]=[Me].[txtID].[Tag]))"
```

Comment: now the entire line appears in red :/ it says "expected end of statement" and highlights me the semicolon at the end of the sentence

Comment: remove the semicolon

Comment: it now says "Runtime error 3075" "Invalid use of '.', or '()'. In query expression '[me].  [txt.Name'.

Comment: is there a space between [me]. and [txtName] ?

Comment: yes there were about 3 spaces but now it says: too few parameters, expected 6.

Comment: this seems to be a problem with your insert statement and not the update statement... as mentioned by @Michael Z. add the values clause

Comment: yeah already did that but the error about the parameters keep appearing

Answer (score 0):

Change the SELECT keyword to VALUES in your INSERT statement.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblClients ( ClientID, ClientName, Gender, " & _
                             "City, [Address (Fisical)], [Cellphone/Telephone] ) " & _
                                "VALUES (" & Me.txtID & ",'" & Me.txtName & "','" & Me.cboGender & "', '" & Me.cboCity & "','" & Me.txtAddress & "','" & Me.txtCellphone & "')"
```

And the UPDATE should be this. The issue here was that you were trying to use `Form` controls in the SQL, but you needed to evaluate the controls first then concatenate their values to your literal string.

I'm wondering if you really need `Me.txtID` instead of `Me.txtID.Tag`
So sway that out if it doesn't work.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblClients SET tblClients.ClientName = '" & me.txtName & "', tblClients.Gender = '" & me.cboGender & "', tblClients.City = '" & me.cboCity & "', tblClients.[Address (Fisical)] = '" & me.txtAddress & "', tblClients.[Cellphone/Telephone] = '" & me.txtCellphone & "' WHERE (([ClientID]=" & Me.txtID.Tag & "));"
```

Comment: yeah, it compiled pretty well but I still am getting the error "Too few parameters expected. Expecting 6" and it highlights me the block below the else statement

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Cableload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37451331/6299399)'s correct answer where the `WHERE` statement that was on a new code line was not connected to the previous line by the use of an underscore at the end of the first one, there is still a referncing issue.

You are referencing values in a UserForm like that were columns in a table so it is not finding the value you are looking for. To get the value into the SQL statement you need to come out of the literal string, reference the value, and then continue writing the string (not forgetting to enclose the value with `'`):  -

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblClients SET " & _
                  "[ClientName] = '" & Me.txtName & "', " & _
                  "[Gender] = '" & Me.cboGender & "', " & _
                  "[City] = '" & Me.cboCity & "', " & _
                  "[Address (Fisical)] = '" & Me.txtAddress & "', " & _
                  "[Cellphone/Telephone] = '" & Me.txtCellphone & "' " & _
                  "WHERE [ClientID]=" & Me.txtID.Tag
```

I have spread it across multiple lines for ease of reading but obviously you can adjust your actual code however needed.

I would also question `[ClientID]=" & Me.txtID.Tag`, is the ClientID in the in the `txtID.value` or the `txtID.Tag`, they are different places. The `value` property is the value in the text box, the `Tag` property is more like a area for metadata that you can populate if needed but is not automatically populated by default.

Finally I'd like to refer you back to an answer to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439053/add-update-button-syntax-error/37441040) you had, at the bottom of the answer there was a tip about placing the resultant query into a Access Query in SQL view to get better information on the error, that would have helped you here too. To give further assistance on the 'resultant query'.

1. In debug mode before the while the `CurrentDb.Execute` is highlighted but before it is run (using F8 to step through each line until you get there, or placing a breakpoint on that line
2. Open the the Immediate Window if it is not already open (either Ctrl+G to from the menu bar 'View' > 'Immediate Window')
3. Copy all related code from the line after the `CurrentDb.Execute` statement, in this case it would be `UPDATE ...  .Tag`
4. In the immediate window type a question mark and then paste in the rleated code and press enter
5. The immediate window will return the resultant string for you to try in a Query in SQL view.

Comment: ClientID it has to be in the .value, I was following a tutorial about adding , deleting, etc. and I followed what the guy said, I tried what you specified me in the other post but still had problems with the code, Ill try what you told me now,  I also opted linking the fields(unbound) to the table but it only gets data from the table, I guess I will start again looking for related videos about that theme